# c# - How to bind values from list in gridview rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach

I have 4 values in List I want to bind that values in gridview row of first column

I tried with the below code but it is overwriting with the last value of list in every row

Code .aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridActivity" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
     BorderColor="#DEBA84" Height="171px" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px" Width="780px">
    <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
      BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
      HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
    <HeaderStyle Width="10px" Wrap="false" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
      BackColor="SteelBlue"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activities">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblActivity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ActivityName") %>' CssClass="columnStyle"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMon" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tuesday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTue" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wednesday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWed" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thursday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtThu" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Friday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFri" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saturday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSat" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sunday">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSun" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Width ="100%"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code .cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DbConnection.Open();
        gridActivity.DataSource = Application["listActivity"];
        gridActivity.DataBind();
        DbConnection.Close();
    }
    if (Application["mondayValues"] != null)
    {
        //Here I can get all the values
        foreach (string mon in Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>)
        {
         //Here is the problem
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gridActivity.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txtMon = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
                txtMon.Text = mon;
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

In the below code I can get all the Monday row values and stored into Application["monday"]

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in gridActivity.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtMon = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
        Application["mondayValues"] = txtMon.Text;
        mondayData = new MondayData { MondayValue = txtMon.Text };
        listMonday.Add(txtMon.Text);
    }
    Application["mondayValues"] = listMonday;
}
```

[image: grid]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see what happens

```
if (Application["mondayValues"] != null)
{
    List<string> monValues = Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>;
    for (int i = 0; i <= gridActivity.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gridActivity.Rows[i];
        TextBox txtMon = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
        txtMon.Text = monValues[i];
    }           
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply but get an error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Comment: I changed the loop condition for (int i = 0; i <= gridActivity.Rows.Count-1; i++) now it's working

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (string mon in Application["mondayValues"] as List<string>)
        {
         //Here is the problem
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gridActivity.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txtMon = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMon");
                txtMon.Text = mon;
            }
        }
```

In the above code you last value in the list Application["mondayValues"], is being assigned to all the text boxes txtMon because you are iterating all the rows and assigning them value, any change made in earlier iteration is being lost.

This code to me is not making much of sense, can you include more details of what you are trying to to, so that we can look into the same.